# Prove that the following relation is a preorder on the set of metrics for $X$ that compatible the topological inclusion

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces, order-theory

> Let be $X$ a set. So if $\delta$ and $\rho$ are two metrics on $X$ then we say that $\delta\preceq \rho$ if for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ exists $\nu_\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ such that
> $$
> \delta(x,y)\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot \rho(x,y)
> $$
> when $x,y\in X$ are such that $\rho(x,y)<\epsilon$.

Now let be $\delta$, $\rho$ and $\sigma$ three metrics on $X$. So first of all we observe given any $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ then any $\nu\in[1,+\infty)$ is such that
$$
\delta(x,y)\le\nu\cdot\delta(x,y)
$$
when $x,y\in X$ are such that $\delta(x,y)<\epsilon$ so that we conclude that the relation $\preceq$ is reflexive.

Moreover if $\delta\preceq\rho$ and $\rho\preceq\sigma$ then for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ there exist $\nu_\epsilon$ and $\mu_\epsilon$ such that
$$
\delta(x,y)\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot\rho(x,y)\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\rho(x,y)\le\mu_\epsilon\cdot\sigma(x,y)
$$
for any $x,y\in X$ whose distance is less than $\epsilon$ with respect $\rho$ and $\sigma$ and thus we conclude that $\nu_\epsilon\mu_\epsilon$ is a positive real number such that
$$
\delta(x,y)\le\nu_\epsilon\mu_\epsilon\cdot\sigma(x,y)
$$
for any $x,y\in X$ whose distance is less than $\epsilon$ with respect $\sigma$ so that we finally conclude that $\delta\preceq\sigma$, that is the relation $\preceq$ is transitive. So we can claim that the relation $\preceq$ is effectively a preorder, **provided that the argumentations I gave are not incorrect**.

Now unfortunately I was not able to prove that if $\delta\preceq\rho$ then the topology generated by $\delta$ is less finer than the topology generated by $\rho$, that is if $\delta\preceq\rho$ then why any open ball of $\delta$ is union of open balls of $\rho$? I tried to prove that if $\delta\preceq\rho$ then there exist a constant $\kappa$ such that
$$
\delta(x,y)\le\kappa\cdot\rho(x,y)
$$
for any $x,y\in X$ but unfortunately I failed. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow the solution proposed by the professor Brian M. Scott in the comments below

So let be $\mathcal T_\delta$ and $\mathcal T_\rho$ the topology generated by $\delta$ and $\rho$. So if $A\in\mathcal T_\delta$ then for any $x_0\in A$ there exists $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ such that
$$
x_0\in B_\delta(x_0,\epsilon)\subseteq A
$$
Now if $\delta\preceq\rho$ there exist $\nu_\epsilon$ such that
$$
\delta(x,y)\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot\rho(x,y)
$$
for any $x,y\in X$ whose distance with respect $\rho$ is less than $\epsilon$.
So putting
$$
\varepsilon:=\min\Big\{\epsilon,\frac\epsilon{\nu_\epsilon}\Big\}
$$
we observe that
$$
B_\rho(x_0,\varepsilon)\subseteq B_\rho(x_0,\epsilon)
$$
so that we conclude that
$$
\delta(x_0,x)\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot\rho(x_0,x)<\nu_\epsilon\cdot\varepsilon\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot\frac\epsilon{\nu_\epsilon}=\epsilon
$$
for any $x\in B_\rho(x_0,\varepsilon)$ and thus we finally conclude that
$$
x_0\in B_\rho(x_0,\varepsilon)\subseteq B_\delta(x_0,\epsilon)\subseteq A
$$
which proves that $A$ is open in $\mathcal T_\rho$ and so
$$
\mathcal T_\delta\subseteq\mathcal T_\rho
$$

Now we suppose that
$$
\delta\preceq\rho\quad\text{and}\quad\rho\preceq\sigma
$$
So if $\delta\preceq\rho$ then for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ there exists $\nu_\epsilon$ such that
$$
\rho(x,y)\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot\sigma(x,y)<\nu_\epsilon\cdot\epsilon
$$
for any $x,y\in X$ whose distance with respect $\sigma$ is less than $\epsilon$ but if $\delta\preceq\rho$ then there exists $\mu_{\nu_\epsilon}\in\Bbb R^+$ such that
$$
\delta(x,y)\le\mu_{\nu_\epsilon}\cdot\rho(x,y)
$$
for any $x,y\in X$ whose distance with respect $\rho$ is less than $\nu_\epsilon\cdot\epsilon$ so that finally we conclude that if $x,y\in X$ are distant with respect $\sigma$ by a smaller amount than $\epsilon$ then
$$
\delta(x,y)\le\mu_{\nu_\epsilon}\cdot\rho(x,y)\le\big(\mu_{\nu_\epsilon}\cdot\nu_\epsilon\big)\cdot\sigma(x,y)
$$
which proves that the relation $\preceq$ is transitive.

Comment: In the fourth displayed line you want $\nu_\epsilon\cdot\epsilon\color{red}{\le}\epsilon$; otherwise it looks okay. You can combine the cases by letting $\epsilon'=\min\left\{\epsilon,\frac{\epsilon}{\nu_\epsilon}\right\}$: then for all $x\in B_\rho(x_0,\epsilon')$ we have $\rho(x_0,x)<\epsilon'\le\epsilon$, so $$\delta(x_0,x)\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot\rho(x_0,x)<\nu_\epsilon\epsilon'\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{\nu_\epsilon}=\epsilon\,,$$ and hence $x\in B_\delta(x_0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, I understood. However now I doubt that the argumentation I gave to prove the transitivity are not correct. Indeed, if $\mu_\epsilon< 1$ then $$\rho(x,y)\le\mu_\epsilon\sigma(x,y)\le\mu_\epsilon\cdot\epsilon< \epsilon$$ provied $\sigma(x,y)<\epsilon$ and so in **this** case $$\delta(x,y)\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot\rho(x,y)\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot\mu_\epsilon\cdot\sigma(x,y)$$ provided $\sigma(x,y)<\epsilon$. However if $1\le\mu_\epsilon$ then how to prove the inequality? could you explain, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: Perhaps I found. If $\mu_\epsilon=1$ then trivially $$\rho(x,y)\le\mu_\epsilon\cdot\sigma(x,y)=\sigma(x,y)<\epsilon$$ provided $\sigma(x,y)<\epsilon$ so that in **this** case $$\delta(x,y)\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot\rho(x,y)\le\nu_\epsilon\cdot\mu_\epsilon\cdot\sigma(x,y)$$

Comment: Finally if $1<\mu_ε$ then $ε<\mu_ε\cdot ε$ so that $$\rho(x,y)\le\mu_ε\cdot\sigma(x,y)<\mu_ε\cdot ε$$ provided $\sigma(x,y)<ε$. Now if $\delta\preceq\rho$ then there exist $\nu_{\mu_ε}$ such that $$\delta(x,y)\le\nu_{\mu_ε}\cdot\rho(x,y)$$ provided $\rho(x,y)<\mu_\epsilon\cdot\epsilon$ but if $\sigma(x,y)<ε$ then $\rho(x,y)\le\mu_ε\cdot\epsilon$ so that we conclude that $$\delta(x,y)\le\nu_{\mu_\epsilon}\cdot\rho(x,y)\le\nu_{\mu_\epsilon}\cdot\mu_\epsilon\cdot\sigma(x,y)$$ provied $\sigma(x,y)<\epsilon$. So we can conlcude that $\delta\preceq\sigma$. So do the theese argumentations work?

Comment: You can even do it all in one. If $\delta\preceq\rho\preceq\sigma$, and $\epsilon>0$, there are $\mu_\epsilon$ and $\nu_{\mu_\epsilon\epsilon}$ such that if $\sigma(x,y)<\epsilon$, then $$\rho(x,y)<\mu_\epsilon\sigma(x,y)<\mu_\epsilon\epsilon\,,$$ and therefore $$\delta(x,y)<\nu_{\mu_\epsilon\epsilon}\rho(x,y)<\nu_{\mu_\epsilon\epsilon}\mu_\epsilon\epsilon\,.$$ Thus, if we set $\lambda_\epsilon=\nu_{\mu_\epsilon\epsilon}\mu_\epsilon$, we have $\delta(x,y)<\lambda_\epsilon\sigma(x,y)$ whenever $\sigma(x,y)<\epsilon$, and it follows that $\delta\preceq\sigma$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh sure, you are right! So thanks very much for your assistance: you was very kind with me, thanks yet. See you soon.

Comment: You’re welcome!